# Where should the page gets redirect if create failed in api

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a rails api. In that if the create in api success then I post it in the api. But if it is not success where should I redirect it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a redirect, you just respond with a different status to notify the frontend that the create failed and, hopefully, why it failed (validations).

This is how a controller generated with scaffold responds by default to json requests.

```rb
def create
  @object = Object.new(object_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @object.save
      format.html { redirect_to @object, notice: 'Object was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @object }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @object.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```